# Manifest Issue in Chrome Store

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been working on a chrome extension for several weeks now and just recently uploaded my extension to the chrome web store.

When I try to install it from the store, it gives me an error saying "Invalid Manifest" and nothing more.

**Is there a way to figure out what is wrong with my manifest file that the chrome store doesn't like?** My browser installs the extension fine (and it works) when I load it in via developer mode.

Since I can't copy it to the code tag and it preview well, I've linked the Manifest file below: [Manifest file on Github](https://github.com/xadamxk/HFX/blob/master/manifest.json)

I've read the manifest v2 documentation and have looked on several google groups for assistance. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: There's a weird file name with a trailing space `ForumDisplay .js`

Comment: Someone here encountered a similar problem due to using an incompatible zip compression, which was solved by using a different archiver. Also, make sure manifest.json is not in a subdirectory inside zip.

Comment: I removed the spacing the name of the js file and the corresponding area in the manifest file - waiting for the store to publish the changes....

As for the zip archive, I just right click the folder and click "Send to ZIP".
Any recommendations for that? (The manifest is at the root of the ZIP) :(

Comment: Just to make sure we're on the same page: zip shouldn't contain any "top" folder that contains all the other files/folders.

Comment: Same page so far - no top folders. The spacing issue didn't seem to fix it.

To make it easier, this is the repo of the extension I am working with.
https://github.com/xadamxk/HFX

All I am doing is zip'ing this folder up on my desktop. (Thanks again for working with me so far)

Comment: Well, then there's the good old divide-and-conquer debugging: delete half the files (also from manifest.json), submit to webstore, and based on the result proceed either with the remaining half of the files or with the other one (restore the deleted files, delete the submitted files). Rinse and repeat.

Comment: 22 updates and 5 hours later, I finally got it all working.
Turns out "Tabs" can not go under permissions, it MUST be an optional permission. AND you must encode the manifest file as UTF-8 rather than ANSI. Thank you for helping me wOxxOm.

I'll mark this question as solved once I get back to my PC.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out "Tabs" can not go under permissions, it MUST be an optional permission. AND you must encode the manifest file as UTF-8 rather than ANSI.

Comment: To avoid misleading info: tabs cannot be mentioned both in optional and normal permissions.